# How to increase query timeout timeout in Aurora Serverless?

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-aurora, aws-aurora-serverless

How do we change the query timeout for aurora serverless? currently it times out at 30s.

Comment: There should not be a "query timeout" in Aurora Serverless.  Are you talking about the timeout that occurs when you attempt to connect to a cold cluster?  If not, what are the cirmstances surrounding the error you are encountering?

Comment: When I fire a particular query it takes a lot of time to execute and fetch the results. So after 30s the connection gets timed out.

Comment: Right -- the *connection* gets timed out -- by the client. 
 You need to increase the timeout on the client side, not the server.

Answer (score 3):

There is currently no way to change query timeout for aurora serverless. The only supported parameters are : https://docs.aws.amazon.com/AmazonRDS/latest/AuroraUserGuide/aurora-serverless.how-it-works.html#aurora-serverless.parameter-groups

The timeout parameters should be added soon until then you can configure you application code such that it completes DB query execution before query timeout period and implement retry mechanishm in case you observe 'Lost connection to server....' Error.

Do refer this link for more: https://youtu.be/4DqNk7ZTYjA?t=2119

Comment: are timeout errors expected? I get them when reading large reading chucks of data in a loop. When working the queries take 2-3sec, then sometimes I loose connection in those queries. Do I just have to deal with it and reconnect, and try to pick up where I left off?

Answer (score 0):

You need to configure your client settings and bump up the connection timeout. Aurora Serverless does not expose a server side param for this.

Answer (score 0):

If you're able to update the app connecting to RDS serverless, you can try increasing the [CommandTimeout](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/dev/connector-net/8.0/html/P_MySql_Data_MySqlClient_MySqlCommand_CommandTimeout.htm) property (or similar property, if you're not using MySQL Connector) of the Command you are executing.

For MySQL Workbench, increasing the [DBMS connection read timeout interval](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/workbench/en/wb-preferences-sql-editor.html) setting worked for me.